# Spring 4 Context loaded twice

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was trying to integrate Quartz Scheduler with Spring 4. However, I noticed that all my classes are loaded twice. I googled a bit and found out that it happens due to the loading of the XML Configuration by both the Dispatcher Servlet Loader and by the ContetxtListener Loader. And removing the  entries will fix the issue. However in my web.xml, I have no such entries.
Any help on what else I may be doing wrong?

EDITED:
I have reduced my project to a very basic implementation of SPRING with Quratz Scheduler and it always loads twice. There is only one class (POJO) in the application which is called through Quartz Scheduler. The POJO prints a message on the console with the hashcode of the object and current time. The message is printed twice for the same time with 2 different hashcodes. The 2 different hashcodes hint at 2 loads of the context.

The project structure is given below:
[image]

The updated web.xml is given below (with no session listener)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>createIdeaPublic</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<display-name>Tractivity</display-name>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
</session-config>
   <servlet>
     <servlet-name>Tractivity</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
     </servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Tractivity</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
  <error-page>
   <location>/jsp/components/jspError.jsp</location>
</error-page>
</web-app>
```

And updated Dispatcher-Servlet xml is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">
<bean id="simpleJobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="quartzExample" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="printMessage" />
</bean>
<bean id="quartzExample" class="com.soft.quartz.QuartzExample">
</bean>
<bean id="cronTrigger"  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="simpleJobDetail" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0/3 * * * * ? *" />
</bean>
<bean  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

The definition of POJO which is called though Quartz Scheduler is:

```
package com.soft.quartz;

import java.util.Date;

public class QuartzExample {

    public void printMessage(){
        System.out.println("Hello Quartz "+this.hashCode()+" " + (new Date()));
    }

}
```

Any idea if its a bug in Spring jar files for this particular release?

Comment: Are they really loaded twice or do you just have a wrong logging setup... And you aren't doing a `new ApplicationContext` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Weird, is by any chance com.soft.utils.SessionListener extending from Spring's ContextLoaderListener? If so it would be loading applicationContext.xml first then tractivity-servlet.xml

Comment: They are really loaded twice. And SessionListener does not extend from ContextLoaderListener.
I have edited the question and removed the SessionListener and other stuff but it still loads the context twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got solved for me. Its due to the Eclipse and Tomcat plugin for Eclipse. My project name in Eclipse was different from the ContextRoot.
Eclipse deployed the application to Tomcat once but the application is accessible through 2 URLS i.e. one for ProjectName and one for Context Root.

1) http://localhost:8080/TractivityPhase2/login --> For project Name

2) http://localhost:8080/Tractivity/login --> For ContextRoot

So actually the application is loaded twice for the 2 URLs.

The issue for me got solved when I made the Context Root equal to my project name. Hope this answer helps someone else.

Comment: Please don't post additions to the question as answers, edit the question instead.